# Copying mutable lists in python

Tags: python, mutable

How not to change value of a list???

```
>>> a=range(0,5)
>>> b=10
>>> c=a
>>> c.append(b)
>>> c
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
```

Until today i didn't know that lists in python are mutable !

Comment: "Mutable" just means you can change it; `c.append(b)` would not work if lists were not mutable. I think you were just unaware that `c=a` does not create a new list distinct from the one referenced by `a`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Followng statement make `c` reference same list that `a` reference.

```
c = a
```

To make a (shallow) copy, use slice notation:

```
c = a[:]
```

or use [`copy.copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy):

```
import copy

c = copy.copy(a)
```

---

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> c = a[:]  # <-- make a copy
>>> c.append(10)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10]
>>> a is c
False
>>> c = a    # <--- make `c` reference the same list
>>> a is c
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making `c` reference the same list as `a`. So to make a shallow copy, use `list()`

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the list into a tuple, which is an immutable list.

[Dive into Python book](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/tuples.html) :

> A tuple is an immutable list. A tuple can not be changed in any way once it is created.

Also

> Tuples can be converted into lists, and vice-versa. The built-in tuple function takes a list and returns a tuple with the same elements, and the list function takes a tuple and returns a list. In effect, tuple freezes a list, and list thaws a tuple.